# How to send mail via sendgrid - node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, sendgrid

I want to use nextjs application to send email by SendGrid, because of its serverless feature. I send my first email via SendGrid demo, just now I want to send a date from my form.

form.js

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import {
    Row,
    Col,
    Container,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Button,
  } from "reactstrap";

function Form() {
    const [hasSuccessfullySentMail, setHasSuccessfullySentMail] = useState(false);
    const [hasErrored, setHasErrored] = useState(false);
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm();
    const { isSubmitSuccessful, isSubmitting, isSubmitted, errors } = formState;
  
    async function onSubmit(payload) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('/api/sendEmail', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ subject: 'Email from contact form', ...payload }),
        });
  
        if (res.status !== 204) {
          setHasErrored(true);
        }
      } catch {
        setHasErrored(true);
        return;
      }
  
      setHasSuccessfullySentMail(true);
    }
  
    const isSent = isSubmitSuccessful && isSubmitted;
    const isDisabled = isSubmitting || isSent;
    const isSubmitDisabled = Object.keys(errors).length > 0 || isDisabled;


  return (
<>
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

                      <Row>
                        <Col lg="6">
                          <FormGroup className="m-t-15">
                            <Input type="text" placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię" id="name" disabled={isDisabled} {...register('name', { required: true })} />
                          </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg="6">
                          <FormGroup className="m-t-15">
                            <Input type="text" placeholder="Twój Email" id="email" disabled={isDisabled} {...register('email', { required: true })} />
                          </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg="12">
                          <FormGroup className="m-t-15">
                            <Input
                              as="textarea"
                              placeholder="Wpisz swoją wiadomość..."
                              id="description"
                              disabled={isDisabled}
                              {...register('description', { required: true })}
                            />
                          </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                        <Col lg="12">
                          <Button
                            type="submit" disabled={isSubmitDisabled}
                            className="btn btn-danger-gradiant m-t-20 btn-arrow"
                          >
                            <span>
                              {" "}
                              Wyślij <i className="ti-arrow-right"></i>
                            </span>
                          </Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form>
</>  )
}

export default Form
```

Problem is that in my console I do not see any headers tag. I look inside Safari > developers tool > network. When I use Mailchimp I can notice that something is sending as post-json in 1sec. Looking into console I get message that something is sending but after 40s as web pack-hmr. I think this is something differ.

in sendMail.js

```
require('dotenv').config(sendgrid.env)
require('dotenv').config(sendgrid)

import sendgrid from '@sendgrid/mail';
    
sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    
export default async (req, res) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const message = `
  Name: ${body.name}\r\n
  Email: ${body.email}\r\n
  Message: ${body.message}
  `;
  
  const data = {
    to: 'ks@gmail.com',
    from: 'biuro@ase.com',
    subject: 'wiadomosc od klienta',
    text: message,
    html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>')
  };
  
  console.log(data)

    sendgrid.send(data);

  
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'Ok' });
};
```

technically, there must be here some mistakes, but SendGrid is good installed and configured. So I need to change only this piece of code.

Comment: Have you tried using `await` before `sendgrid.send(data)`?

Comment: Yuap, not work. Mail provider told that do not see any try of SMTP contact from SendGrid. And Sendgrid send that they receive my mails and send forward to provider and he must have firewall or something. 
Finally, I change sendgrid to Nodemailer. This work me perfect. I do not know how the security is.

Comment: Please [edit] the question when responding to clarifications in the comments. Comments are not part of the Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used SendGrid as it is an external resolver API I did this in my API portion of next.js and works correctly.

```
// api/mail
import { news_letter_template } from "../../../util/email_templates";
 const sendGrid = require("@sendgrid/mail");
  sendGrid.setApiKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENDGRID_KEY);
  // add this before handler!
  export const config = {
    api: {
       externalResolver: true,
    },
  };
export default function handler(req, res) {
 const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  console.log('request came => ',body);
  const msg = news_letter_template(body.email);
  sendGrid
   .send(msg)
   .then(() => {
      return res.status(200).json({ send: true });
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     return res.status(400).json({ send: false });
   });
 }
```

setting `externalResolver` to `true` made my code works correctly.

```
//utils/email_templates
const SENDER_EMAIL =
 process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENDER_EMAIL || "Support@weblog.com";
 const weblog_social = {
 insta: "https://www.instagram.com/weblog",
 fb: "https://www.facebook.com/weblog",
 linkedIn: "https://www.linkedin.com/company/weblog",
};

const news_letter_template = (reciverEmail) => {
 const msg = {
    to: reciverEmail,
    from: SENDER_EMAIL,
    subject: "newsletter",
    html: `<p>Dear subscriber,</p><p>Thanks for signing up for  
    newsletter!</p>
    <p> looking forward to hearing from you. </p>
       <p><a href="${weblog_social.insta}">Instagram</a></p>
      <p><a href="${weblog_social.fb}">Facebook</a></p>
        <p><a href="${weblog_social.linkedIn}">LinkedIn</a></p>
      `,
      };
       return msg;
     };

    export { news_letter_template };
```

Comment: How looks email_template? I guess something missing in my code.

Comment: let me to edit my answer and add email_template function.

Comment: The function just returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

I have answer for my first of problem. My SendGrid post date to api/contact but there something not work as it should.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import {
    Row,
    Col,
    Container,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Button,
  } from "reactstrap";

function Form() {    
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('')
    
    async function handleOnSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = {
            name,
            email,
            message
        }
        console.log("przesylam dane");
        
        setSubmitted(true)
        
        fetch('/api/contact', {
            method: 'POST',
     
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        }).then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log("czyszcze pola")
                setSubmitted(false)
                setName('')
                setEmail('')
                setMessage('')
                setStatus('success')
            }
            else {
                console.log("pokazuej blad")
                setStatus('error')
            }
        }) 
    }
    
    return (<>
<Form action='submit' method='POST' onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
<Row>
<Col lg="6">
        <div id="name" isRequired className="m-t-15">
            <Input             style={{width: "100%"}}
placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię" type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} />
        </div>
        </Col>
        <Col lg="6">
        <div id="email" isRequired className="m-t-15">
            <Input             style={{width: "100%"}}

placeholder="Wpisz swój adres email"  type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
        </div>
       </Col>
       <Col lg="12">
        <div id="text" isRequired className="m-t-15"> 
        <Input
                              as="textarea"            style={{width: "100%"}}
                placeholder="Wpisz swoją wiadomość.."
                value={message}
                onChange={(e) => { setMessage(e.target.value) }}
            />
        </div>
     </Col>
     <Col lg="12">

        <Button type="submit"
            isLoading={submitted}
            loadingText="Submitting"
            className="btn btn-danger-gradiant m-t-20 btn-arrow"
            style={{width: "200px"}}

        >
         {" "}
                              Wyślij <i className="ti-arrow-right"></i>        </Button>
    </Col>
    </Row>
    {status === "success" ? <span style={{color: "green"}}>wiadomość przesłana</span> : ""}
    {status === "error"  ? <span style={{color: "red"}}>wiadomość nie została wysłana</span> : "" }
    </Form>
</>    )
}
    
export default Form
```

Comment: Please share what result you're getting.

Comment: ``` 202
{
  server: 'nginx',
  date: 'Wed, 01 Jun 2022 22:01:17 GMT',
  'content-length': '0',
  connection: 'close',
  'x-message-id': '5YmJYJohQ-C658yOC_Fbew',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
  'access-control-max-age': '600',
  'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
} ```

Comment: A 202 response means that the API request was a success and the email is queued to be sent. If it still didn't send, there might be something else wrong with it. Are you sending from an email address on an [authenticated domain](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) or using a [verified email](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification)?

Comment: I am using  verified email as a email from. I have also authenticated domain. I checked in activities in SendGrid at no have emails send by this script. Just 4 one which I send to verified email/domain.